# Redirect virtual location "C:/Users/Admin/Projects" to "/Volumes/Projects" in macOS

Tags: macos, adobe-premiere, apfs

I'm attempting to set up a workflow where it is possible to open a Premiere Pro project located on a Windows 10 PC in `C:/Users/Admin/Projects` on a macOS machine, located on the same network.

By sharing the `Projects` folder through my local network, I can open the Premiere Pro project on the Mac, the directory of which is simply `/Volumes/Projects`. However, Premiere is still searching for all the media files in the `C:/Users/Admin/Projects` location, which obviously doesn't exist on the mac, as the correct directory is instead `/Volumes/Projects`.

Is there any way I can tell either macOS or Premier Pro to redirect any traffic towards the non-existent `C:/Users/Admin/Projects` towards `/Volumes/Projects` instead?

Comment: Is the project file for Premiere a text file that you can edit?  If so, try to change from absolute paths to relative paths, in the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to just create it and symlink to the correct location. Because macOS (like other Unix systems) does not have drive letters, the `C:/` is just a relative path for a regular directory named "C:".

So assuming the program starts with your home `~/` as the "current directory",

```
mkdir -p ~/C:/Users/Admin

ln -s /Volumes/Projects ~/C:/Users/Admin/Projects
```

might do the trick.